# When render a .jade, Node.js cannot find the static files

Tags: node.js, express

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfX1K.png)

It's OK that I can get files in directory public when get `localhost:3000/movies`, but if I add `/` to the end of URL, that is `localhost:3000/movies/`, something goes wrong, the CSS file in public cannot be get. How do I solve this problem if I want to visit `localhost:3000/movies/moive` with CSS style?

Comment: If you could share how you have express configured, that would help a lot. Also, it'd be nice if you tried just a *little* harder on your question. You left the link to the image title "enter image description here"... where you should have put an image description. It looks like there's something wrong with either your static handler or with how the page is asking for resources cause when you go to /aMovieChart/ it's not asking for the `_include` resources from the root of the site anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When you are at `localhost:3000/movies`, think of being in "folder" `/` and viewing "page" movies. If you are in `localhost:3000/movies/blah` or in `localhost:3000/movies/` then you are viewing pages `blah` (or `/` respectively) in the `movies` location.

The above is true regardless those "pages" exist or not; most likely you just have express route handlers and jade templates structures differently -- but the rationale works for the browser and the requests to absolute URLs it will be performing.

So I cannot say what is wrong without looking at your pages code, but make sure all relative paths (e.g. linking to a CSS file `foo/bar.css`) are valid from all locations, or alternatively use absolute locations (e.g. `/foo/bar.css`).